# It's legal to mix c++0x threads with gio GCancellable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, glib, c++11, gio

If I'm not wrong there is no easy way to make a c++0x thread cancellable. I'm wondering if it's legal to use [GCancellable](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.29/GCancellable.html) mixing it with c++0x thread.

If the answer is

> No

I guess I should use [glib threads](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Threads.html) or it's not so legal too?

Comment: What makes you think that? It's quite easy if you provide the appropiate interruption points and/or check the cancelation status.

Comment: @K-ballo What do you mean for "the appropiate interruption points"? About checking the cancelation status, well I can do this but I really should prefer to use GCancellable if it's legal, because the code will be cleaner. Excuse me if I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment. It seems that the `std::thread`s didn't ended up with the interruption functionality from `boost::thread`s, so please just disregard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very familiar with `GCancellable.`  After a quick read through, it appears to be a hierarchical notification system.

If that is the case then yes you can easily mix `GCancellable` with `std::thread`.

---

> There is no easy way to make a `std::thread` cancellable.

This is wrong.

> There is no non-zero cost way to make all `std::thread`s cancellable.

This is correct.

The problem is providing a general solution.  Notification is easy enough.  The hard part is making sure the thread sees the notification.  The thread may be blocked on a mutex or IO.  You ***cannot*** just kill the thread.  All sorts of bad can occur.

Each individual implementation is free to implement their own cancellation system tailored to you particular needs.

If you need to be interruptable from a blocking mutex, make sure you only use timed_mutexes, and that you call `g_cancellable_is_cancelled` frequently enough that your thread will cancel as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like [boost's interruptible threads](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-interruption-in-boost-thread-library.html)?

This aspect didn't make it into the standard but you can **derive from `std::thread`** to offer a protected `check_interrupted()` method which throws if someone called a public `interrupt()` method.

I wouldn't bother mixing with Gnome's thread constructs. Sounds like more trouble than it's worth.